# Are finite projective modules locally free without axiom of choice?

Tags: commutative-algebra, axiom-of-choice, projective-module, free-modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. An $A$-module $M$ is called a finite projective module if there exists a module $N$ and a natural number $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $M\oplus N\cong A^n$, and an $A$-module $M$ is called (Zariski-)locally free if there exists a finitely many elements $f_1,\dots,f_n\in A$ such that $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ generates the unital ideal, that is to say, $(f_1,\dots,f_n)=A$, and that the localizations $M_{f_i}:=M\otimes A_{f_i}$ of the module $M$ at $f_i\in A$ are free for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

**Remark:** The terminology (Zariski-)locally free is reflected by the fact that the maps $\operatorname{Spec}(A_{f_i})\to\operatorname{Spec}A$ constitute a Zariski cover.

**Question:** Is it true that all finite projective modules over a commutative ring are locally free without axiom of choice?

It is known that this is [true](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00NX) if certain version of axiom of choice is allowed, essentially the existence of prime ideals, which is equivalent to a weaker version of axiom of choice, for the equivalence see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98549/ or https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27163/.

It is worthwhile to mention that finite projective modules are also free over noncommutative local rings. See Weibel's [Kbook, Chapter 1](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/Kbook/Kbook.I.pdf) Lemma 2.2.

Now I am asking whether we can avoid axiom of choice to prove this statement? By avoiding AC, it is easier to find analogues for other topoi.

Comment: This seems to be true without AC, theorem X.1.5 in [Lombardi-Quitté](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.02942). I will check the details. The idea is to write out the matrix of the projection and analyze the minors.